# Compress the table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two tables, but here only half of the table is visible which is overlapped by another table
So, I want to compress the table to make both table visible.

I've tried css,html,js to compress, doesn't work out.

Can anyone suggest on this
Thanks in advance.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BkrR.png)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLRdu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is by simply using Flexbox. Unless Flexbox has set the `flex-wrap` property to `wrap` it will squish the elements by itself to fit the width of `auto/100%`.

However, by default, the tables will only occupy the width they need which you can prevent by using `flex-grow: 1` to order them to grow to fill the remaining space:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

table {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 1</th>
      <th>Row 2</th>
      <th>Row 3</th>
      <th>Row 4</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 1</th>
      <th>Row 2</th>
      <th>Row 3</th>
      <th>Row 4</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```